# Convert the string to integer in mongo aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My company has inserted numerical values for certain keys in string format. They can't be converted to integer format for some business reason.

Now coming to the query...

I am writing a mongo aggregate query which calculates `annual cost` for a **particular manufacturer** like Unilever across shops. It seems I cannot convert a string to integer inside the `$cond` and `$eq` blocks using `$toInt` method.

Please find below the sample collection.

```
[
 {
  _id: "ddfdfdfdggfgfgsg",
  rate: "3323",
  quantity_packs: "343",
  shop_name: "Whole Foods",
  manufacturer_name: "Unilever"
 },
 {
  _id: "ddfdfdfsdsds",
  rate: "434",
  quantity_packs: "453",
  shop_name: "Carrefour",
  manufacturer_name: "Unilever"
 },
 {
  _id: "dfdfdgcvgfgfvvv",
  rate: "343",
  quantity_packs: "23",
  shop_name: "Target",
  manufacturer_name: "Beirsdorf"
 }
]
```

The query is

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            manufacturer_name: {
                $in: [ "Unilever" ]
            }
        }
    }, 

    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "Shop Name": "$shop_name"
            },

            "annual_cost": {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        {
                            $eq: ["manufacturer_name", "Unilever"]
                        },
                        { "$toInt": "$rate"}, 
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },

            "other_annual_cost": {
               $sum: {
                   $cond: [
                      {
                         $ne: [$manufacturer_name, "Unilever"]
                      }, {"$toInt" : "$rate"},
                      0
                  ]
               }
            },

            "annual_qty": {
                $sum: {
                    "$toInt": "$quantity_packs"
                }
            },
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {

            "Purchase_Cost": {
                $multiply: [ "$annual_cost", "$annual_qty" ]
            },

            "Other Manu Pur Cost": {
                $multiply: ["$other_annual_cost", "$annual_qty"]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Current Output**

```
[
  {
    _id: { 'Shop Name': 'Whole Foods' },
    Purchase_Cost: 0
  }
]
```

As `$rate` is of string type, the multiplication has yielded `0` as shown over [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6NLdV-nCb-9). Ideally the result should show some integer value for purchase cost as shown below.

**Intended Output**

```
[
  {
    _id: { 'Shop Name': 'Whole Foods' },
    Purchase_Cost: 234
  }
]
```

Any suggestion would be of great help. I want to make this query work somehow.

---

I have updated the question based on Rajdeep's Answer.

Comment: you can get help from here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/

Comment: @ArvindPal I know $toInt does the type conversion. But how to use it and where to use it in my context? I want to convert the $rate to integer before I use it in $cond block.

Comment: The $toInt is working fine, the trouble is that your "annual_cost" result is 0, so at the end when you multiply it, you get 0 aswell.
What is your expected value in "annual_cost"? Why ara you using sum on a condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just corrected this, please take a look

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k63ViHhVMEO)

```
"annual_cost": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$manufacturer_name", //added $
                "Unilever"
              ]
            },
            {
              $toInt: "$rate" //added $toInt
            },
            0
          ]
```